# how to pass data from file outside angular library to files inside of angular library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below are the files of a library named `posts-lib` which makes http call inside `posts.services.ts` file and receives a list of posts and display them onto screen. It also consists a component named `title.component.ts` which is dependent on `posts.services.ts` and is responsible for displaying content on screen.

All of this works fine, but incase I want to move `posts.service.ts` folder out of the library and put it inside the app then how can I transfer the data from file which is outside of the library to the file `title.component.ts` which is dependent on it.

title.component.html

```
    <h1>Testing titles api call</h1>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.title}}</li>
    </ul>
```

title.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'lib-tilte',
      templateUrl: './tilte.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tilte.component.css']
    })
    export class TilteComponent implements OnInit {
    
      data: any;
    
      constructor(private postData: PostsService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.postData.getPosts().subscribe((result) => {
          console.warn("reult",result);
          this.data = result;
        })
      }
    
    }
```

posts-lib.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'lib-posts-lib',
      template: `
        <p>
          posts-lib works!
        </p>
      `,
      styles: [
      ]
    })
    export class PostsLibComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

posts-lib.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { PostsLibComponent } from './posts-lib.component';
    import { TilteComponent } from './tilte/tilte.component';
    import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
    
    
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        PostsLibComponent,
        TilteComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      exports: [
        PostsLibComponent,
        TilteComponent
      ]
    })
    export class PostsLibModule { }
```

posts.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PostsService {
    
      url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      getPosts() {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
      }
    }
```

public-api.ts

```
    export * from './lib/tilte/tilte.component';
    export * from './lib/posts-lib.service';
    export * from './lib/posts-lib.component';
    export * from './lib/posts-lib.module';
    export * from './lib/posts.service';
```

Comment: why do you need to get the service out of its library. If so, you need to move the components also outside (library will be empty). OR you keep the service where it is, which is already exported via `public-api`, and use it in other modules by declating it as one of the providers.

Comment: @Prajwal we need to keep on changing code inside posts.service.ts (e.g. URL) time to time. So to prevent updating library again and again is there a way we can make changes within this file only and let data to be transferred to library.

Comment: If you are modifying your package from time to time, it is always better to update the package every time you make changes across all libraries. That's the best approach I could possibly think of.

Comment: why would you keep a library if you don't want to import it anywhere else? If you are importing it somewhere else, then why shouldn't you update your package?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the issues the commenters are making - all valid - it sounds like you want to just remove the dependency on the service.

Or not, actually.

Yay, options!

1. Remove usage of the service

Just turn the component around from getting its own data, to being given its data. I.e. `@Input`.

2. Still with `@Input`, but instead, input the service itself rather than the values.

So either:

```
@Input() public data: any;
```

or

```
@Input() public set service(value: PostsService) {
    this.postsService = value;
    this.getData();
}

private getData(): void {
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(...);
}
```

Either way if you're moving the service out and no longer expecting the service and component to work as a functional pair within a system, you have to extract the component and feed it information instead with `@Input`s.

Whether that's just feeding it the data from [a wrapper] service, or feeding it the service itself from wherever it now lives, you still need to give it to it.